# billboard.js chart svg larger than div?

Tags: html, css, billboard.js

Placeholder text:

[image]

AreaChart from https://naver.github.io/billboard.js/demo/#Chart.AreaChart:

[image]

You can see the HTML in the above snip for the next two images:

[image]
[image]

What's going on here? The closest thing I could find was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51100573/billboardjs-chart-bigger-than-its-container). The parent is 75% width of its parent which is 100% width of the center. I thought it might be a conflict with bootstrap, but removing the "col" class only removed the "gutter" (padding). Curiously, if I open/close the dev menu (F12), it resizes correctly:

[image]